# How can I integrate Jenkins with Redmine?

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, redmine, redmine-plugins, jenkins-plugins

I would like to integrate Jenkins with Redmine. If some build breaks, Jenkins would open an issue in Redmine to notify it with the console output.

How can I do it? Are there any plugins? Are there any implementation guides? I couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this

1. install hudson plugin inside redmine, see http://www.redmine.org/plugins/t-ando_redmine_hudson , it will let you know the build inside redmine. (**2014.5.7 [Updated] change to redmine plugin list **)
2. install redmine plugin inside jenkins (hudson), unfortunately the plugin is not maintained any more, https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Redmine+Plugin . And JIRA jenkins plugin is a way how redmine plugin should be supported. 
   (**[Updated] the plugin is back since 2013**)

[updated] I tried to add this functions for solution 2 in 2011.2, see my blog: http://larrycaiyu.com/blog/2011/02/24/associate-ci-build-information-in-redmine-issue-by-using-redmine-rest-api/, but I stopped after that, because

1. In the community, it seems solution 1 is preferred.
2. lots of functions are already inside JIRA, it is better to persuade them to make it as a common issue plugin inside jenkins.

Comment: Well that's not exactly what I am looking for, those plugins doesn't report failed builds as a redmine issue

Comment: so you mean http://codeslife.com/2011/02/24/associate-ci-build-information-in-redmine-issue-by-using-redmine-rest-api/ which i tried one year ago?

Comment: Yes, Is it stopped since that post?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer for the reason. And if your needs is simple, then the change is not so much, while to make that plugin works in all the case, it will be complicated.

Comment: update: is seems the jenkins-redmine plugin is actively developed again (3 new releases since your answer)

Comment: @LarryCai The link for the Hudson plugin seems to be changed. Could you edit it?

Comment: @Enmos:guess it is temple down, anyway I changed to redmine plugin list where you can see code repo and webpage as well

Answer (score 2):

You can try the e-mail-to-issue option in Redmine.

1. Configure Jenkins to send an e-mail to Redmine with detailed report.
2. Configure Redmine to accept the e-mail and transfer it to the issue.

You can configure whatever template you wish so the reports will be user-friendly. Further more Redmine has a simple incoming mail parser so that you can omit info you don't need.

No plugins needed, only settings in both tools.